# White flickering/flash between pages in phonegap iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, cordova

I'm using phonegap for my iOS app.

For some reason, when I navigate through my app, there is a split second of white flicker/flash between pages.

I did not use jquery mobile, I only used some javascripts and iScroll4 that's all. Is there anyway to resolve this problem?

**EDITED**
Here is some part of the code.

Index CSS:

```
body { 

-webkit-user-select: none; 
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
background-color: #f7f6ec;
overflow-y: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 }

#fixedcontent {
    position:absolute; z-index:1;
    top:64px; bottom:49px; left:0;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Index.html

```
<html>
    <head>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />


       <!-- fixed header -->
       <script src="js/iscroll-lite.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">

           var myScroll;
           function loaded() {
               setTimeout(function () {
                          myScroll = new iScroll('fixedcontent');
                          }

                          document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

                          document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);

                          function onCompletion () {
                          // Here modify the DOM in any way, eg: by adding LIs to the scroller UL

                          setTimeout(function () {
                                     myScroll.refresh();
                                     }, 0);
                          };


                          </script>

    </head>

<body>
<div id="wrappercontentfixed"> hi test
<a href="about.html"> about page </a>
<a href="merchandise.html"> merchandise page</a>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any time the dom changes you recall the load function which call after Timeout myScroll.refresh(). How do you handele the "between pages" action tap on link?

Comment: Sorry, as I'm a beginner in programming stuffs, I don't really get it. I have edited a little more in the html part. I linked pages just by normal linkage, for example my about page only contains HTML/CSS codes, there's still flash/flickers between my home page to about page.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possible reasons for that.
Maybe it's the [webkit-tap-highlight-color](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-tap-highlight-color) you can change in css to `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` for the element with that flashing effect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have tried it, but it couldn't work, there is still the flash between pages. I have added in my index.css body.

Comment: Post some code to make it understandable for everyone what you did